# Is there any in built function to read each and every item present in listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to add that item in a particular textbox like an image for each item there should be a particular textbox for that item 
for one item it is working but if i choose multiple item then it is not coming only one item is coming[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quHEO.png)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me, but if you're asking how to access the (multiple) selections in a multi-select listbox then there's the `SelectedItems` (plural) property for that.

Comment: My question is i have a listbox in that 5 items are there i have to choose that item and  put into a text box ,each item should be filled its own seperate textbox so,  if i choose one item it is coming but if i choose multiple item it is not coming

Comment: <asp:ListBox ID="lstbxid" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
                 <asp:ListItem>Mango</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>papaya</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>orange</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>Banana</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btnid" runat="server" Text="Select"  OnClick="btnid_Click" />